# Function in the object refering to another some value but the property been assigned to another value why?

Tags: javascript

Recently while working with javascript object in my chrome console I got confused with the log information about my object,Please help be understand it.

```js
function makeFunction()
{
  this.name="Some Name";
  this.display=function(){return this.name;};
  this.returning=function(){return this.display;};
}
    
var object1=new makeFunction();


console.log(object1);//First console log of object1


object1.name="Another name";//trying to change the property of object1

console.log(object1);//Second console log of object1
```

I updated the name property of object1 but when the result was printed it seemed like this

[The references to the name in display function in first console log is changed but the original reference seemed to be "Some Name" only can anyone explain why?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZDST.png)

Comment: The code appears to work fine in the snippet. The Chrome console is notorious for being asynchronous and misleading in cases like this.

Comment: Chrome's console log will keep a reference, so when you expand it for more details it will evaluate the current state, this is normal..